# Get result of Hibernate's commit

Tags: hibernate

I need to check, if the commit of hibernate is successful. In particular, if an item was successfully deleted from the database, then delete it from a table on a JSF page.

```
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

How can I handle it?

Comment: if it executes without throwing an exception, then it's successful.

Answer (score 1):

commit()  has a void return type so that won't tell you much unfortunately.

However,  it looks like Transaction has a wasCommited method. 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Transaction.html

That should do what you want. If it doesn't then you can always query again for the item. That's less than ideal since you're hitting the DB again but it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Hibernate 5, there was a wasCommitted() method on the Transaction interface. However in version 5 and beyond, this method has been removed and you need to use the TransactionStatus to determine the state of the Transaction.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Transaction.html
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/resource/transaction/spi/TransactionStatus.html

In your case you could check the status of a transaction like this :

```
if(session.getTransaction().getStatus() == TransactionStatus.COMMITTED){
    // do something
}
```

The different statuses available to work with are ACTIVE, COMMITTED, COMMITTING, FAILED_COMMIT, MARKED_ROLLBACK, NOT_ACTIVE, ROLLED_BACK & ROLLING_BACK.